# Navigation bar does not render correctly when logo is added

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I seem to have hit some weird css issue where I can't get my nav to render correctly.
The Facebook and Twitter portions are running into each other and I'm not sure where in the CSS I can edit it.

CSS:

```
ul
{
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
}

li
{
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
 float:left;
}

a
{
 font-family: Verdana;
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
 padding: 10px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
color: #55a1c8;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul><li><a href=Purchase.html id="current">Purchase The Book</a></li>
                    <li><a href=About.html>About The Characters</a></li>
                    <li><a href=Games.html>Games</a></li>
                    <li><a href=LoggedIn.html>Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href=https://www.facebook.com/AmazingAdventuresSeries target="_blank"><img src="http://www.irscstudentweb.org/~S14006548/images/logos-and-badges_f-logo_online/png/FB-f-Logo__blue_29.png" alt="Find us on Facebook"></a></li>
                    <li><a href=twitter.com/neesyboowookus target="_blank"><img src="http://www.irscstudentweb.org/~S14006548/images/Twitter_follow.png" alt="Follow us on Twitter" height=29px></a></li>
        </ul>
```

There is some other CSS as well, and I've tried to remove the other formatting to see if it is causing a problem. Doesn't matter if it's there or not.
Here is a fiddle to see in action: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=R7hj7mcuFU

Comment: First of all, why is your site a table ???? Secondly why are img and div positioned absolute????

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for a fix, or are you just going to be snarky and type lots of question marks?

Comment: Yes, as a suggestion I would say learn some html and css :) And secondly here you are the fix http://jsfiddle.net/58ophaxw/ :)

Comment: Your fix caused the table below (the one that overlays the picture) to move and run into the logo. I will keep working on it.

Comment: Updated http://jsfiddle.net/58ophaxw/1/ :) And please in future don't use tables for layout http://phrogz.net/css/WhyTablesAreBadForLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look too bad at present, but to enhance it further you could add padding to the left or right of the social network images you are using.

To get the white background to display, remove "position: absolute" from your  CSS.

Comment: The twitter logo is running into the Facebook logo and does not appear to be part of the nav bar. It is not included within the white background of the Nav bar either. When I used the Follow @twitter handle logo, it went to a separate line below the facebook logo or was on top of the facebook logo.

Comment: See my revised answer above.

Comment: I will try doing that. It's definitely weird, b/c I added a white background to see what was going on, and I'm noticing even though the twitter logo is part of the nav list, it's not part of the white background. It just seems like something weird is going. Thanks.